# How to add test authorization with inherited TestContext in BUnit?

Tags: c#, xunit, bunit

I have an inherited TestContext in BUnit and I want to add the Testauthorization.

This doesn't work:

```
using Bunit;
using Bunit.TestDoubles;
public class TestClass : TestContext
{
        [Fact]
        public void CompTest()
        {
            AddTestAuthorization();
        }
}
```

if I use the "normal" version with the boilerplate code like following it works.

This works:

```
using Bunit;
using Bunit.TestDoubles;
public class TestClass
{
        public void CompTest()
        {
            TestContext ctx = new TestContext();
            ctx.AddTestAuthorization();
        }
}
```

So my question is, how to add test authorization with **inherited** TestContext in BUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `AddTestAuthorization` is an extension method, you need to use `this` to get to it. Its an unfortunate limitation in the C# language.

E.g.:

```cs
using Bunit;
using Bunit.TestDoubles;
public class TestClass : TestContext
{
        [Fact]
        public void CompTest()
        {
            this.AddTestAuthorization();
        }
}
```